# XRDP clipboard to allow copying only text

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clipboard, vdi, xrdp

I am setting up RDP to login to a Linux instance from windows instance. I am trying to restrict the clipboard in XRDP to copy only text but not files, Please help me with the options available. The cliprdr either allows copying files/text/zip files and setting it to false disables copy completely. Please suggest if there are any options to set up the clipboard size or allow only text to be copied

Answer (score 0):

This feature was requested in the post
[Is there a way to disable copy/paste file but keep copy/paste text functionality? #423](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/423).

The only advice given was to remove fuse as workaround:
`apt remove fuse`. This didn't work for the poster but may be
worth trying, since it also came up in the post
[Clipboard won't transfer file #220](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/220),
where missing fuse was part of the problem.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, this did not workout for me either